# Xamarin.mac Draw a graph

Tags: graph, drawing, core-plot, xamarin.mac

I am getting quite desperate with this, having searched the internet for several days no one seems to have ever tried to draw a graph using xamarin.mac, which i find very hard to believe ! I cannot install core plot, oxy plot etc, because of a bug with the installer, trying to install either gives:

"Could not install package 'xamstore-coreplot 1.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

or equivalent.

Can someone please either help me fix the above error, or help me draw a graph in xamarin.mac using core graphics or something ? I really only want to plot a line graph from a set of points, i didn't think it would be that hard !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This might be the case since Xamarin.Mac is newish. Although MonoMac has been around, it was just a .NET 4.5 app that had fancy packaging. Now, it is a fully featured binding for Cocoa with the same level of support as Xamarin.iOS.

Answer (score 1):

That error is stating the fact that there is no mobile (Xamarin.Mac, Version=v2.0) build of the library. If there is a "desktop", but you might be able to swap the [target framework](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/advanced_topics/target-framework/) of your project.